# Show that $(1-it)|\psi\rangle-it\langle x|\psi\rangle|x\rangle$ is $|\psi\rangle$ rotated into the $|x\rangle$ direction

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

[image: pi]

Here $|\psi\rangle$ is an $n$ component unit vector with $|x\rangle$ being one of the unit basis vectors, i.e., $|\psi\rangle=a_1|x_1\rangle+a_2|x_2\rangle+\cdots+a_x|x\rangle+\cdots+a_n|x_n\rangle$ and $\exp(-iHt)$ is a unitary operator since $H=|x\rangle\langle x|+|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ is hermitian.

$$
H=|x\rangle\langle x|+|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|\quad\&\quad\exp(-iHt)\approx I-itH\\
\exp(-iHt)|\psi\rangle=(I-itH)|\psi\rangle=(I-it|x\rangle\langle x|-it|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|)|\psi\rangle\\
=(1-it)|\psi\rangle-it\langle x|\psi\rangle|x\rangle
$$

How can we interpret from $|\psi(t)\rangle=\exp(-iHt)|\psi\rangle=(1-it)|\psi\rangle-it\langle x|\psi\rangle|x\rangle$ that the vector $|\psi\rangle$ is rotated into the $|x\rangle$ direction by the action of $\exp(-iHt)$ ?

**Reference :** [Page 257, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)

**My Attempt**

$$
|\psi\rangle=a_1|x_1\rangle+a_2|x_2\rangle+\cdots+a_x|x\rangle+\cdots+a_n|x_n\rangle\\
\langle x|\psi\rangle=a_x\\
\langle x|\exp(-iHt)\psi\rangle=(1-it)a_x-ita_x=(1-2it)a_x=\frac{1-2it}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\times\sqrt{1+4t^2}\times a_x=e^{i\theta}\sqrt{1+4t^2}\times a_x
$$
Consider another state $e^{-i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ which has the same characteristics as the state $|\psi\rangle$ because having an overall phase does not change the probability which is the amplitude squared.

The angle between $e^{-i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ and $|x\rangle$ is such that $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1+4t^2}a_x>a_x\implies$ the angle is lesser than that between the original state $|\psi\rangle$ and $|x\rangle$.

Is it an explanation for the required statement in my reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left out or missed a very important piece of information: the Hamiltonian is defined as

$$H=|x\rangle\langle x|+|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$$

They then truncate the expansion of the exponential Hamiltonian:

$$\exp(-i Ht)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n H^n t^n}{n!}=I-itH-\frac{H^2 t^2}{2}+...\approx I-itH$$

Then

$$\exp(-i Ht)|\psi\rangle\approx (I-itH)|\psi\rangle$$

Using this truncation and the definition of $H$ gives

$$(I-itH)|\psi\rangle=(I-it|x\rangle\langle x|-it|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)|\psi\rangle=(1-it)|\psi\rangle-it \langle x|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle$$

---

EDIT: So when they say its been rotated slightly in the $|x\rangle$ direction they mean

$$|\langle x|\psi\rangle|^2<|\langle x|\exp(-iHt)|\psi\rangle|^2$$

To see this, note that

$$\langle x|\exp(-iHt)|\psi\rangle\approx \langle x|[(1-it)|\psi\rangle-it \langle x|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle]$$

$$=\langle x|\psi\rangle-it\langle x|\psi\rangle-it\langle x|\psi\rangle^2=a_x-it a_x-it a_x^2$$

However, note that we can multiply $|\psi\rangle$ by $e^{i\phi}$ for any $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$ without changing the overall absolute value. Thus, choose $\phi$ such that

$$a_x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Taking the absolute value of this (with $a_x=a$) gives

$$|a_x-it a_x-it a_x^2|^2=a^2 (1  + (1 + a)^2 t^2 )$$

while on the other hand we have

$$|\langle x|\psi\rangle|^2=|a_x|^2=a^2$$

Thus, to show we have rotated in the $|x\rangle$ direction we simply need to show

$$a^2  (1 +  (1 + a)^2 t^2 )-a^2  >0$$

This is equivalent to showing that

$$ (1 + a)^2 t^2 >0$$

which is always true unless $|\langle x|\psi\rangle|=1$. But this is fine since that would imply $|\psi\rangle$ was already pointed in the $|x\rangle$ direction so $H$ would have no effect on it.

Comment: Thanks for responding and sorry for not mentioning the hamiltonian. But i understand this math on how to reach $(1-it)|\psi\rangle-it\langle x|\psi\rangle|x\rangle$, my boubt is how do we say that it is $|\psi\rangle$ rotated into the $|x\rangle$ direction ?

Comment: I have edited the post to better explain my doubt, could you please comment on it ?

Comment: okay thanks for the edit. I have added a "my attempt" section in the post, can it be an explanation for the rotation towards $|x\rangle$ other than the magnitude squared which is the probability of obtaining $|x\rangle$ ?

Comment: Yeah, your proof looks good to me